# Path around rectangular fountain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A landscaper is designing a rectangular fountain with a 4-foot-wide path around it. The equation $A = 4p + 64$ will relate the area $A$, in square feet, of the path to the perimeter $p$, in feet, of the fountain. In the design, how many feet will the perimeter of the fountain increase for each additional square foot of the path’s area?

The answer is **1/4**, but I do not know how. Anyone please show me with every vital steps?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is the inverse of the coefficient $4$ of $p$.  If you add $1$ to $A$, you have to add $\frac 14$ to $p$ to maintain the equality.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I felt that the OP needed a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This question, like many SAT questions, is just asking you to think about the meaning of the slope of a line.

In this case, the problem is asking: if you increase $A$ by 1, by how much does $p$ increase? Part of the test is whether you recognize that this is precisely the kind of question the slope of a line helps us answer.

You are given $A$ as a linear function of $p$, namely $A=4p+64$, so you can easily read off the slope, which is 4. But what does this mean? Saying the slope is 4 means that when $p$ increases by 1, $A$ increases by 4. In other words, the ratio

$$\frac{\text{change in A}}{\text{change in p}}$$

is 4 to 1.

Hence if we want $A$ to increase only by 1, we should increase $p$ only by $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$A = 4p+64$.

If the area increases by $1$,
and the new perimeter is
$q$,
then
$A+1 = 4q+64$.

Subtracting these,
$1
= (A+1)-A
=(4q+64)-(4p+64)
=4q-4p
=4(q-p)
$.

Therefore,
$q-p$,
which is the amount that
the perimeter increased by,
satisfies
$q-p = \dfrac14
$.

This is where the answer comes from.

Comment: I think this is unnecessarily complicated: the real issue is whether the student understands slope as a rate of change. Your answer of course explains that idea, but it doesn't say the word "slope," which is the word the test writers will have had in mind. (A large number of SAT questions are about interpreting the slope and intercept of linear models. This is one of those questions.)

Answer (score 0):

There are correct and good answers here.  Here's a simpler one that's also a test taking strategy.  (Some regulars on this site might not appreciate this approach but I've frequently seen this strategy [successfully] taught.)

You want to know the following:

> If I increase $A$ by $1$, how much will $p$ increase?

We could analyze it in general.  **But because there's only one right answer (which we can infer from the question's phrasing, and it's especially clear if it's a multiple choice question), we can just plug in specific *and convenient* values and see what happens!**

What makes a value convenient?  It really depends on the problem.  In this case we would like to pick a value of $A$ such that solving $A = 4p+64$ for $p$ is "easy."  In theory, any value of $A$ will work, but because $4p$ and $64$ are both multiplies of $4$, then a convenient value of $A$ will be any multiple of $4$ large enough to give us a positive $p$.

So let's try $A=80$.  This gives us $$80 = 4p+64.$$ Solve this to get $p=4$.  Now let's add $1$ to $A$ and see what happens.

If we have $A=81$, then we get $$81=4p+64.$$ So then $4p=17$, and so $$p =\frac{17}4 = 4.25 = 4+\frac14.$$

Therefore, $p$ increases by $1/4$ whenever$A$ increases by $1$.

Comment: If you're going to mention this kind of cheat, you might as well explain what made you choose $A=80$ rather than, say, 1 or $\frac{3}{4}$ or $\pi$. "Plug in values" is not a good strategy in itself: it is only the beginning of one, because it can quickly lead to a whole lot of tedious & time-consuming arithmetic if not not carefully. (So it'd be worth saying you picked a multiple of 4 because the right-hand side has multiples of 4.) What you really mean is "plug in *convenient* values," where convenience depends on other features of the problem.

Comment: @symplectomorphic thanks, updated.  I also don't care for "plug in specific values" strategies in general, but I see it so frequently in test prep books and (back in the day anyway) taught in test prep courses, and as far as I can tell it's a helpful and successful strategy for those who are not mathematically inclined.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the path is given by $A = 4p+4\times (4\times 4)$: $4p$ makes for the four segments of path along each side of the rectangle, and you add four times a $4\times 4$ "square feet" squares to connect the segments at corners.

If you enlarge the base rectangle, you will change the perimeter, hence the surface of the four segments. But the four  $4\times 4$ "square feet" squares won't change. So the surface of the path will vary only from the $4p$ term. In other words, the difference between the area for two designs varies $4$ times faster than the perimeter. This linear dependence tells you that if the perimeter varies by $1$, the area will vary by $4$, whatever the initial area. This is a proportional effect, or the slope some people here are asking for. So for the area to vary by 1, the perimeter should vary by $1/4$. We are now ready for equations.

If the surface increases by 1 square foot, i.e. $A' = A+1$, what will be the new perimeter $p'$? $A' =4p'+64$, and you know that $A =4p+64$, so $4p+64+1 = 4p'+64$, which reduces to $4(p'-p)=1$, so the perimeter variation is $p'-p =1/4$.